# Is it possible to download magazines as single PDF in IEEE Xplore with an institutional subscription?

Tags: online-publication, ieee, digital-libraries

In the past, as a subscriber of IEEE Security & Privacy, I was able to download the entire magazine as a single PDF.

Since I started using IEEE Xplore from the university, however, I can only download an article at a time which is quite annoying. Is there a way to download a full magazine as a single PDF using an institutional subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible, at least not with IEEE Xplore.

In fact, they explicitly disallow this. See http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/termsOfUse.jsp (Point 4 of the "Do Not"s for Institutional Subscribers). So it is not surprising that there is no technical support for doing that.

As an individual former subscriber of "IEEE Security & Privacy", they may have granted you that right. Interestingly, under the "Do Not"s for IEEE Member access to IEEE Xplore, the point about downloading whole issues is missing. So that may be part of the reason.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote that particular bullet point in your answer for completeness?

Comment: The page states "Institutional subscribers are NOT permitted to do the following: [...] - Download or attempt to download an entire issue or issues of a publication contained in IEEE Xplore. [...]"